# How to use binary file as input of File Uploader

Tags: angularjs

this is my first post here,not sure how things work around here,but hey you gotta start somewhere.

I'm using a package from angular called angular-file-upload to upload images.
Is it possible to use an image from clipboard as input of file-uploader?

Comment: This component doesn't support pasting from clip board

Comment: ok, got it,thx m8

Answer (score 0):

This component doesn't support pasting from clipboard.

Please experiment with [ClipboardEvent.clipboardData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent/clipboardData) to see how clipboard data is handled.

Also try using the paste event handler to trigger function on user pasting data.

```
document.addEventListener('paste', my-function);
```

Lot of security implications are around this event and the browser support is not yet impressive.

But it is a nice ground to do some experiments on.

Comment: ok, I think I get the concept now, so I need to write my own function to do the upload(or find some existing ones),and this function need to support this kind of input.